# css issue on IIS

Tags: asp.net, css, iis-7

I have a web site published. The CSS files and styles just work fine on my local machine. But whenever I put it on the server, they do not work. The server is Windows Server 2008 R2 and is configured to have [static content enabled](http://gurustop.net/blog/2009/10/12/funny-problem-windows-7-iis-7-5-images-css-not-showing/).

Any idea please?

Comment: How are you linking the CSS and JS files? Are you deploying them correctly?

Comment: The link you provided is something almost 3 years old and answered in the post comments. 
So is there actually a question?

Comment: Did you check the paths to the resources?  If you view the page source and browse to the CSS files you can see if they exist on the server.  If you are using relative paths, they may not match with the directory structure on the server.

Comment: Lets be constructive here, @Ktt please provide some code on how your referencing(MastPage, .aspx) your CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by server because of high level protection. my collegue had to put cookie then it worked.

```
   <authentication mode="Forms">
         <forms loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" timeout="2880"/>
       </authentication>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" 
        href='<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/yourpath/yourcss.css") %>' />
```

Comment: Is your css file on the server?